# clickhouse - max_concurrent_queries to a higher number

Tags: clickhouse

My queries which are very short lived run for about 200-400 ms each have 20 UNION ALLs, which query a merge view(which contains 3 views), where each of it is a distributed view which redirects it to a shard.
This will quickly increase the number of queries if we start doing multiple of the types of queries.

What would be the recommended practice ? can increase the max_concurrent_queries to 1000

We are using 16vCPU, 60 GB RAM machines. we want to increase the max_concurrent_queries to a number like 1000. is this recommended? I see the docs say 100 is the recommendation, is this not a function of the machine type?
or is it a clickhouse implementation limitation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100 just a default value (safe-limiter) which is suitable for Yandex, you can set any value.

There is Engine=Merge https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/merge/ . I recommend to try it instead of UNION ALL

Comment: Thanks, we are using merge views for our underlying tables. 
but the queries we are doing UNION ALL are very different queries that use different columns and different lookups. 

We will try increasing the configs.

Comment: 1)So, every query in the UNION ALL will add to the number of concurrent queries right? 
2)Also, every query queries  a merge view with three underlying distributed views, all this will add up to the number of concurrent queries? 
20 * 3

Comment: @SaurabhDaga What is  "merge view"?

Comment: I meant https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/merge/
the merge table

Comment: How high a number have you stress tested your cluster? not that we will follow this just so that we have rough idea. 
FYI, my queries are very simple lookups with very minimal aggregations(like 20-100 rows) not very intensive

Comment: When it will be 20 queries (20 union all). You can set any number as you want. Yandex tries to fail faster and don't overload their cluster because they have 10-thousands users and 500 servers. (I don't work in Yandex).